# Skipping Tasks Listed as Dependencies in Gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have looked all over the documentation and NPM to try to find a solution to this, but I have had no luck. I would like to have the option to skip the tasks that I list as dependencies when running a specific task. For example, if I have the following:

```js
gulp.task('prerun', function(){
  // do cleaning, installation, etc.
});

gulp.task('run', ['prerun'], function(){
  // do stuff
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('glob/glob/**', ['run']);
});
```

I would like to be able to have my `gulp.watch` execute `run` without having to touch the overhead involved in `prerun`. Is this at all possible in Gulp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's about a helper task? I use this approach to eliminate any dependencies in my watch tasks. Your example can look like this:

```
gulp.task('prerun', function(){
    // do cleaning, installation, etc.
});

gulp.task('run', ['prerun'], function(){
    gulp.start('run-dev');
});

gulp.task('run-dev', function() {
    // do the run stuff
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('glob/glob/**', ['run-dev']);
});
```

The prerun task you can also use as dependency for your watch task if needed:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['prerun'], function(){
    gulp.watch('glob/glob/**', ['run-dev']);
});
```

Ciao
Ralf

Comment: I was thinking about taking this approach, but from my understanding, it is not particularly good practice to use `gulp.start` (it might get removed in the future). This would make the task a lot easier, though!

Answer (score 0):

Without using `gulp.start`, you can try this:

```
gulp.task('prerun', function(){
    // do cleaning, installation, etc.
});

// run all dependencies while keeping run-dev as a separate task
gulp.task('run', ['prerun', 'run-dev']);

gulp.task('run-dev', function() {
    // do the run stuff
});

gulp.task('watch', ['run'], function(){
    gulp.watch('glob/glob/**', ['run-dev']);
});
```

Comment: Won't the 'run' task here run 'prerun' and 'run-dev' simultaneously?

Comment: Yes. Dependencies run async.