# Ignoring task dependencies in gulp.js

Tags: javascript, build, dependencies, gulp

I have the following task

```
gulp.task('sass-build', ['clean-build'], function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

which obviously requires `clean-build` to be finished before starting. However, I would also like to use this task with `gulp.watch` without the `clean-build` dependency.

I'm aware that you could solve this with a helper task like suggested in [Skipping Tasks Listed as Dependencies in Gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374533/skipping-tasks-listed-as-dependencies-in-gulp), but this would require using `gulp.run` (which is deprecated) or `gulp.start` (which isn't even documented because it's considered bad practise).

What would be a better way of doing this? Or is the only way to use `gulp.run` or `gulp.start`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach showed in the linked question is actually not that bad. Instead of `gulp.run` you can use simple functions which do the same:

```
var sassFunction = function() {
    return gulp.src('blahbla')
        .pipe(bla())
}

gulp.task('sass-build', ['clean-build'], function () {
    return sassFunction()
});

gulp.task('sass-dev', function () {
    return sassFunction();
});


gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('your/sass/files/**/*.scss', ['sass-dev'])
});
```

Your other approach is also not so bad and will be fully incorporated with Gulp 4.

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clean-build', gulp.parallel('sass-build')));
```

Something to look out for, since it changes dependency trees completely.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence). This also made the entire multitask order much clearer.

What I did exactly was remove the `clean-build` dependency from `sass-build`. So eventually:

```
gulp.task('sass-build', function () {
    // do stuff
});

gulp.task('build', function () {
    runSequence('clean-build', [..., 'sass-build', ...], 'index-build');
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('src/sass/*', ['sass-build']);
});
```

Very convenient!